# Using type alias in template with the same type with template class it self

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand some code in [singly_linked.hpp](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/libcaf_core/caf/intrusive/singly_linked.hpp):

```
template <class T>
struct singly_linked {
  // -- member types -----------------------------------------------------------

  /// The type for dummy nodes in singly linked lists.
  using node_type = singly_linked<T>;  // exactly type of node_type???

  /// Type of the pointer connecting two singly linked nodes.
  using node_pointer = node_type*;

  // -- constructors, destructors, and assignment operators --------------------

  singly_linked(node_pointer n = nullptr) : next(n) {
    // nop
  }

  // -- member variables -------------------------------------------------------

  /// Intrusive pointer to the next element.
  node_pointer next;
};
```

what is the exactly type of `node_type`? Does it causes a infinite loop? For example if I have:

```
singly_linked<int> node;
```

then what is the type of `singly_linked<int>::node_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand meaning of `using node_type = singly_linked<T>;`. It does not declare a variable of type `singly_linked<T>` (which would indeed lead to infinite recursion and would cause a compiler error). Instead, this introduces an alias for this type: `singly_linked<T>`.

Thus, asking about type of `singly_linked<int>::node_type` does not make sense, since it is a type itself.

Comment: so, `singly_linked<int>::node_type` is still `singly_linked<int>`?

Comment: @maidamai Yes, it is... It does not seem to make sense at a first glance, but the alias might be used in other templates, e. g. `template <typename T> void f() { typename T::node_type n = ...; }`